# android quiz radio buttons do not display the correct value

Tags: java, android, random

I created this algorithm to generate randomly generated numbers. For some reason the fake answers and the right answer don't output the right result.  I dont understand why the answer is returned some of the time but other times the right answer returns the wrong answer. I am wondering if the shuffling of the array is working incorrectly. Could someone shed some light on this problem.

```
public void randomGenerator()
{

    int Min = 1;
    int Max = 99;

    int numberText  = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    int numberText2 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    num1_text.setText(String.valueOf(numberText));
    num2_text.setText(String.valueOf(numberText2));
    answer = numberText + numberText2;
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "what is the value for the answer "  + answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    int randomoption1  = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    int randomoption2 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
```

Comment: You can use [`Random.nextInt(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) to generate a random integer in range `[0,x)`

Comment: out of interest what is the problem so I understand how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: I doubt it was the problem, if I thought it was - I'd post it as an answer. I just reference you to an easier way to create random integers in the future.

Comment: thanks amit that's very helpful. Is there a problem with the shuffle array is the input being produced in a certain way that is causing it to work sometimes and not others.

Comment: Don't see where you're making the call to `answers()`.  How are you producing the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want to generate a number between 1 and 99.

```
int numberText  = Min + (int)(Math.random() * Max)+1;
int numberText2 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * Max)+1;
```

This works fine :)